# Scraping web-page with button-multitems click

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, button, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'am trying to scrape this web page: https://whalewisdom.com/filer/fisher-asset-management-llc#tabholdings_tab_link

I would like to setup the python selenium code, in order to setup correctly multitems in: "50" pages per page

[image]

But my code click on wrong button. where is my code error?

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary_location = r'C:/Users/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:/geckodriver.exe' , options=options)
driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://whalewisdom.com/filer/fisher-asset-management-llc#tabholdings_tab_link'})
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[@id='qtr-1-label']"))))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle']"))).click()
```

thank you for your help.

-ag

Comment: Hi Himan! I answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code clicked on wrong button because you have multiple elements with exact same class and you are fetching the first one and clicking on it.

[image]

Also I see on the page, you sometime get a popup which may make other elements not interactable. SO we would want the popup to close first(if appeared) then move ahead.

#### Using Chrome driver

###### Setup and Imports

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# REPLACE YOUR CHROME PATH HERE
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"

s = Service(chrome_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
```

###### Fetch the page

```
driver.get(' https://whalewisdom.com/filer/fisher-asset-management-llc#tabholdings_tab_link')
```

###### Close the popup(if appeared)

```
try:
    popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='dfwid-close-184302']")))
    popup.click()
except TimeoutException:
    print("No Popup appeared on the page")
```

###### Click on dropdown and the menu item 50

```
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btn-group.dropdown')
dropdown.click()
ele50 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//li[@role="menuitem"]/a[contains(text(), "50")]')
ele50.click()
```

###### Output

The above code clicks on item 50

[image]

#### Using Firefox driver

The imports would be same as above, the following code would also remains some with just a minute change.

```
# REPLACE YOUR FIREFOX DRIVER PATH HERE
firefoxpath = r'C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\firefoxdriver\geckodriver.exe'
s = Service(firefoxpath)
driver  = webdriver.Firefox(service=s)
driver.get(' https://whalewisdom.com/filer/fisher-asset-management-llc#tabholdings_tab_link')

try:
    popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='dfwid-close-184302']")))
    popup.click()
except TimeoutException:
    print("No Popup appeared on the page")
  
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btn-group.dropdown')
dropdown.click()
ele50 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//li[@role="menuitem"]/a[contains(text(), "50")]')
ele50.click()
```

###### Output

which similarly clicks on the desired element

[image]

Comment: Seems perfect! But i'am using firefox. Can you modify youre code for firefoxe use? Thanks

Comment: okay, wait a jiffy doing that

Comment: @AgustosImola check my updated answer, let me know if it helps

Comment: Okay!! Thank you so much! give me a second

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247084/discussion-between-agustos-imola-and-himanshuman).